# 24 Bit Unsigned Integer

Tags: javascript, c++, c, byte, bit-shift

I start working with HART (Highway Addressable Remote Transducer) Protocol and I found something, let's say different and I try to understand it, more precisely the uint24. I understand that this structure uses an UInt32 internally for storage and most other common expected integer functionality, so using a 24-bit integer will not save memory. But my question is how can I convert an UInt32 to this specific type, I found these lines of code in Javascript but I don't know what is the purpose of those left shifting.

```
var getUint24 = function(bytes)
{
    return (DataView(bytes.buffer).getUint16(0) << 8) + DataView(bytes.buffer).getUint8(0 + 2);
}
```

Also, I found this function that convert a number to 4 bytes. I also don't know what is the purpose o these shifting, but maybe if I understand these I can create my own version of the function that convert a simple number ex: 4  to his uint24 version.

```
/**
 *
 * @function ToBytesInt32 "Convert number to 4 bytes (eg: ToBytesInt32(2) returns 00 00 00 02"
 * @param {number} num The input value
 * @return {byte array}
 */
function ToBytesInt32BigEndian(num) {
    if (isNaN(num)) {
        throw "ToBytesInt32 received Nan! Called from: " +
        testUtils.StrReplace.caller.toString().split('\n')[0];
    }
    arr = [
        (num & 0xff000000) >> 24,
        (num & 0x00ff0000) >> 16,
        (num & 0x0000ff00) >> 8,
        (num & 0x000000ff)
    ];
    return arr;
}
```

If anyone can help me to understand the pourpose of those shifting I would apreciate it, also the C/C++ version is very welcomed.

Comment: Normally an unsigned integer is stored in memory as its hexadecimal representation (very different for other types). Left/right shifting just "moves" some positions the bytes towards left/right, filling the new holes with zeros and losing the moved-out bytes. Moving to the right-most position gives you an unique byte. The masks used with `&` just select some positions and makes the rest to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

- left `<<` shifting is a padding of significant bits with zeros for future conjunction into single value;
- right `>>` shifting is part of extracting of value's segment into smaller data type (goes after applying mask);

### Abstract

Shift & sum is the way to pack/unpack values when reading/writing frame is less of value's length. Let's say we have 4 bit value: `1011`. And we able read it only by 2 bit frames: `[10], [11]`.

Let's assume that we are reading stream from left to right.

```
# offset 0 bits
a = stream(0)      # a = 10
a << 2             # a = 1000

b = stream (2)     # b = 11

return a + b       # 1000 + 11 = 1011
```

Also you should pay attention to BE/LE (Big/Little Endian). In different Endians value `1011` may be presented in stream as `10, 11` or `11, 10`.

### getUint24 example

In case of `getUint24` example we have 24 bit value packed as sequence like `[16 bit, 8 bit]`. Let's draw it as `[XY, Z]` where single letter is 1 byte.

```
# offset 0 bytes
a = DataView(bytes.buffer).getUint16(0)      # a = XY
a << 8                                       # a = XY0

# offset 2 bytes
b = DataView(bytes.buffer).getUint8(2)       # b = Z

return a + b                                 # XY0 + Z = XYZ
```

And again `bytes.buffer` may keep value either as `[XY, Z]` or `[Z, XY]`. The `getUintX(offset)` hides this details from us. But if you'd like to write own converter, you need investigate what format is in your case.

### ToBytesInt32BigEndian example

Here we see another concern of packing values - apply mask.

For say we have 32 bit value `AB CD EF 12`. We can apply mask to extract needed segment of the value.

For example, if we have 3 bit value `011` and would like get value of second bit we need apply &-mask where subject bits evaluated against `1` keep original value while rest bits evaluated against `0` turn any value into `0`.

```
masked    = 011 & 010    # 010
bit_value = masked >> 1  # 001
```

In the same way with our `ABCDEF12`

```
x = 0xABCDEF12 & 0xFF000000   # x = 0xAB000000
x >> 24                       # x = 0x000000AB
...
```

This way we will get array `[0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF, 0x12]`. Without shifting we were get array `[0xAB000000, 0x00CD0000, 0x0000EF00, 0x00000012]` which is not what we want.